# Can i apply for H1B visa from Netherlands being an Indian Expats

Tags: usa, working-visas, netherlands, h1-visa

I am from India came to Netherlands as an expat, i have  valid residence permit till 2016. Can i apply H1B visa from Netherlands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're a legal resident in The Netherlands, then the US embassy there should be able to process your application.